# Sachs-Wolfe effect

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmic-microwave-background

So for photons at the bottom of the well at the time of last scatter, they will climb out of it losing energy. But, from there on, the potential wells (density fluctuations) do not just disappear, so those photons will keep going through the "uphill" and "downhill" motion while travelling towards us, so why wouldn't the effect even out by the time we receive the photons? Why is it guaranteed that these photons will still look cooler due to the initial climb?

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/739260/2451

Answer (score 1):

There are two reasons the "uphill" and "downhill" motion do not always cancel out.

1. The photon originated at the top or bottom of a hill. This is the ordinary Sachs-Wolfe effect. It implies that (at large scales) hot spots on the observed cosmic microwave background (CMB) came from *cold spots* in the early universe, and vice versa. This is because hot spots have excess density, which gravitationally redshifts exiting photons, cooling them beyond their original temperature excess.
2. The hill's height changed between the photon's descent and its ascent. This is the integrated Sachs-Wolfe effect. It generally does not happen during the matter epoch; density variations then grew both in amplitude and in size (the former due to gravity and the latter due to cosmic expansion) in such a way that the potential remained constant. However, that was not true during a brief time period shortly after last scattering, because there was still a significant radiation density at the time, which slowed the growth of structure. It is also not true today, because dark energy is slowing the growth of structure. Thus, both shortly after the CMB was emitted and at recent times, gravitational potentials decay, leading to integrated Sachs-Wolfe effects.

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not clear exactly why any effects later on would not erase or even reverse the "cooling" effect due to the "initial" climb.

Comment: Not sure if I'm misunderstanding, but if we neglect integrated Sachs-Wolfe (ISW) effects, then the photon climbs out of its initial well, and then in subsequent wells/hills it always gains or loses the same amount of energy entering as leaving. Thus the effect of the initial well persists. Now, if we account for ISW effects, then they can induce persistent random redshifts/blueshifts along the photon's path. If the photon is lucky, its initial cooling could be canceled by that.

Comment: "If the photon is lucky, its initial cooling could be canceled by that." Right exactly, so how can we use the observed fluctuation to infer the initial condition/original SW, if it's all messed up by the ISW?

Comment: It's just a matter of statistics. We don't really care specifically which spots in the early universe were hot or cold, we just care about the statistical distribution of hot and cold spots. That distribution is modified by ISW in a way that we understand. [Figure 1 of this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.5018.pdf) nicely shows how different effects combine to produce the observed CMB power spectrum, which is basically a statistical description of how extreme the fluctuations are as a function of their angular size $\theta\sim 1/\ell$ (large $\ell$ = small size). Blue is SW, magenta is ISW

Comment: Huh nice figure. I guess I just don't quite get why the ISW wouldn't completely wash out any correlation due to SW. Wouldn't a photon encounter ISW randomly?